# git update branch to current state (weird named branches in origin)

Tags: git

Im now in the branch "development"

if I type

```
git branch -a
```

I see that I have plenty branches like:

```
remotes/origin/BRA1
remotes/origin/development
remotes/origin/tests
```

I would like reset all my code to the online branch "development"

Is it a right way?

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/development
```

or

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard remotes/origin/development
```

I dont want to save my local changes ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches work and are equivalent.